# Why models loads recursive?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have one-to-many relationship. Use EntityFramework. Two models:

1.
***Record***: *List Attempts;*

2.
***Attempt***: *long RecordId;  Record Record;*

```cs
var record = this.db.Records.Include(x => x.Attempts).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == recordId);
if (record == null)
{
    return this.NotFound();
}
```

When i load data from db loads main record, then loads attempts inside record, and inside each attempt loads record etc.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Is the record inside the attempt virtual?

Comment: No. Need to write virtual Record?

Comment: I set public virtual Record Record but it does not help me

Comment: But isn't the "Record" the same for each included "Attempt"?

Comment: Do you get any exception or error for this recursive loading?

Answer (score 1):

For this behavior, it is default behavior.

> Entity Framework Core will automatically fix-up navigation properties
>   to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context
>   instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a
>   navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or
>   all of the related entities were previously loaded.

Source:[Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading).

If you got any serialize error, you could try [Related data and serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization)